# A method that only calls other methods?

Tags: java, methods

Would it make sense to have 3 methods such that:

Method1 performs actionA
Method2 performs actionB
Method3 calls Method1 and Method2 so you don't have to manually call Method1 and Method2?

Ex:

```
private void method1()
{
 //does smth
}

private void method2()
{
 //does smth else
}

private void method3()
{
 class.method1();
 class.method2();
}
```

Edit1: thanks for all the answers! =)

Comment: It can be right or wrong, depending on the context of how the methods interact between them.

Comment: This is way too broad to answer, unless you have a specific context under which you're doing this. In some cases, this may make sense; in others, it may not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of several reasons why it might make sense. Maybe it just makes sense logically to separate out the actions that methods 1 and 2 perform. Or maybe you want to call method 1 or 2 from places other than in method 3. You generally want your code to be "modular" as possible, which can often lead to patterns such as the one you bring up.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I do that a lot. I think it makes sense, and can be really useful for keeping the amount of function calls down, because otherwise you'd have to call both 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

If 3 operations make sense in the context of domain, then it is good practice, cause clients of `operation3` are less coupled to your service class and logic of `operation3`.

By the way if you always call `operation1` and `operation2` together, then you shall do this, make the two private, and decouple the clients from them.